# What conditional excel formula should I use?

Tags: excel

I am a newbie in excel.
Please refer my excel workbook snapshot by clicking this link :

[image]
Currently the formula I have is such that ***if D137 and E137 are blank, then F137 is also blank***. However, ***if the values in D137 and E137 are identical, the F137 shows 'Correct' and if the values are different then F137 shows 'Wrong'***. *I want to add one more condition without changing any of the previous conditions*. The *new condition is*, ***If D137 is blank but there is a value in E137 then F137 should show 'Wrong'***. How do I edit my formula to do that?

The current formula is pasted below:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(D137),ISBLANK(E137)),"",IF(D137=E137, "Correct", "Wrong"))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your last/new condition is the same  as your "if the values are different then show wrong" condition. Just change that OR() to an AND() and I think you'll have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult. All you have to do is remove the first condition that you are checking if D137 is blank. It actually makes the formula shorter. See below.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E137),"",IF(D137=E137, "Correct", "Wrong"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much Peter. Exactly what I wanted.